# Can't call method in Observer. Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Here is how i describe sales_order_place_after event

```
    <models>
        <chatattributes>
            <class>Rockstar_Chatattributes_Model</class>
        </chatattributes>
        <chatattributes>
            <class>Rockstar_Chatattributes_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>chatattributes_resource</resourceModel>
        </chatattributes>
        <chatattributes_resource>
            <class>Rockstar_Chatattributes_Model_Resource</class>
        </chatattributes_resource>
    </models>
</global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <place_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>chatattributes/observer</class>
                        <method>placeOrder</method>
                    </place_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <quote_item>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>chatattributes/observer</class>
                        <method>setQuoteItem</method>
                    </quote_item>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_set_product>
            <add_to_cart_before>
                <observers>
                    <add_to_cart>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>chatattributes/observer</class>
                        <method>addToCart</method>
                    </add_to_cart>
                </observers>
            </add_to_cart_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Here is my Observer.php (Rockstar/Chatattributes/Model/Observer.php)

```
<?php
class Rockstar_Chatattributes_Model_Observer
{
    public function placeOrder($observer) {
        var_dump('Never Ever change Magento Core code'); die;
    }

    public function setQuoteItem($observer) {
        var_dump('quote item'); die;
    }

    public function addToCart($observer) {
        var_dump('added to cart'); die;
    }
}
```

So, when i placing order i want call method 'placeOrder' in my observer...but i can't.....i have been delete VAR folder and create it again with 777 permissions.

Comment: did you write any more custom observer method here?

Comment: yeah, i have updated the question....take a look please

Comment: can't call two custom observer method. verify this post link http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/how-to-create-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento/

Comment: yeah, nice link about orders..but i have a problem with Observer. var_dump don't working when i placing order or add it to cart(see new event which i have added).

Comment: About custome methods....could you please show me how to create custome methods in one observer and call them in some events ?...

Comment: only one custom observer method will work. If you have any other custom observer method, it doesn't take your new observer method

Answer (score 1):

//Put under global tag & not under frontend tag

```
<global>

        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <place_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>chatattributes/observer</class>
                        <method>placeOrder</method>
                    </place_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>

</global>
```

Comment: are you still using `CompanyName_ExtensionName` instead of `Rockstar_Chatattributes` on your Observer.php ...i think.. not. But if yes that will be a very minor mistake

Comment: i tried to show example...i am using Rockstar_Chatattributes

Comment: btw...in magento 1.7 observer events are working fine when i have override them in <frontend><events>....not in <global> node

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, you are looking for the Observer class with the 'chatattributes' model.
That shorthand for the model needs to be defined and related to a model class in the XML.
For the model that you gave, the XML model definition would look like:

```
   <global>
     <models>
      <chatattributes>
       <class>CompanyName_ExtensionName_Model</class>
      </chatattributes>
     </models>
    </global>
```

Comment: Hello Laizer, thank you for answer. I have updated my question with model node. Please check it.